# Equality of continuous functions on the closure of a subset

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be two topological spaces and $U \subseteq X$ a subspace. Let $f,g:X \rightarrow Y$ be two continuous function such that $f(x) = g(x)$, $(\forall) x\in U$. Is it true that $f(x) = g(x)$, $(\forall) x\in \overline{U}$?

At first thought, the answer seemed to be "Yes", but I could not find the proof. If $Y$ is Hausdorff, then indeed the answer is "Yes". The proof goes like this:

Suppose that there is some $x \in \overline{U} \backslash U$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, there exist some disjoint open neighborhoods $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively. Then $f^{-1}(V_1) \cap g^{-1}(V_2)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ which does not intersect $U$. This is a contradiction!

However, I don't know how to manage the situation when $Y$ is not Hausdorff. Is the property also true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, and $Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the trivial topology. Any map $X\to Y$ is (trivially) continuous in this case. So for example, the constant function $f(x)=1$ and the indicator of the rationals $g=1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ are continuous functions which agree on $\mathbb{Q}$, but not on its closure in $X$.